# How to specify where to push using docker buildx build command

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I was reading the docs regarding `docker buildx build` to build to multiple architectures and I got puzzled with the `--push` option, it says that it pushes to the registry directly but how does it know or how can I specify where I want it to push the built images?

For more context, my plan is to push the images to my Gitlab private container registry from my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Comment: just specify your registry in the tag myregistry.com/myImage:latest (and dont forget to docker login myregistry.com)

Comment: Aaaah sorry I didn't know you could specify also the registry inside the tag, I will try that as soon as I get back to my PC if you want to answer that I'll gladly accept it as an answer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First login to your private registry, with the command `docker login myregistry.com`. After that specify your registry in the tag name of your image `docker buildx build --push -t myregistry.com/appname:version .` and it should push your image to myregistry.com after build.

Note: Docker looks for either a “.” (domain separator) or “:” (port separator) to learn that the first part of the repository name is a location and not a user name.